# Adding and correcting simulation data with pandas?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I'm running a MD simulation. I'm interested about cluster growth in the system, and so the data produced by the simulation is of form:

```
nmax simtime
6    2.3e-9
7    7.1e-9
8    1.7e-9
11   1.1e-8
13   1.8e-8
```

Where nmax is the biggest cluster present. Obviously, since a cluster of size 8 has appeared after 1.7ns, there must have been clusters of sizes 6 and 7 before that. Furthermore, I would like the data to include missing cluster sizes, like 1,2,3...9,10. So the result would look like this:

```
nmax simtime
1    1.7e-9
2    1.7e-9
...
6    1.7e-9
7    1.7e-9
8    1.7e-9
9    1.1e-8
10   1.1e-8
11   1.1e-8
12   1.8e-8
13   1.8e-8
```

I'm using python 2.7 and pandas. Previously I've used the shift function to make new shifted simtime columns and then compared these new columns to the original simtime column. Original value gets replaced by the shifted value, if the latter is smaller of two.

Problem occurs when the amount of data increases. This method I'm using needs an increasing amount of shifted columns, which results in ugly and probably inefficient code.

So: 1) how to fix incorrect simtime values effectively and 2) include sizes not present in the original data file?

Answer (score 0):

I think shifting is the wrong approach, as e.g. for your first row, the comparison with the next element will be valid.
`2.3e-9` is smaller than `7.1e-9` (assuming I understood you correctly).

Instead, you can iterate the rows backwards, comparing always two **valid** (meaning non-nan) simtime values. Afterwards, you can simply reindex and fill up nans by taking the next non-nan value in the dataframe.

---

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

# prepare test data
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'nmax': [6, 7, 8, 11, 13],
        'simtime': [2.3e-9, 7.1e-9, 1.7e-9, 1.1e-8, 1.8e-8]
    });
df['nmax'] = df.nmax.astype(int)
df = df.set_index('nmax')
print(df)

# set illegal simtime values (bigger than next non-nan value) to nan
for i_curr, i_next in reversed(list(zip(df.index, df.index[1:]))):
    simtime = next(s for s in df.loc[i_next:].simtime if not math.isnan(s))
    if df.loc[i_curr].simtime > simtime:
        df.set_value(i_curr, 'simtime', np.nan)

# fill index with missing indices and fill nans by taking the next value
df = df.reindex(range(df.index[-1] + 1)).fillna(method='bfill')

print(df)
```

**Results**

```
           simtime
nmax              
6     2.300000e-09
7     7.100000e-09
8     1.700000e-09
11    1.100000e-08
13    1.800000e-08
           simtime
nmax              
0     1.700000e-09
1     1.700000e-09
2     1.700000e-09
3     1.700000e-09
4     1.700000e-09
5     1.700000e-09
6     1.700000e-09
7     1.700000e-09
8     1.700000e-09
9     1.100000e-08
10    1.100000e-08
11    1.100000e-08
12    1.800000e-08
13    1.800000e-08
```